# How can I self-define a keyboard entry for 3-dot "Because"?

Tags: symbols, keyboard, logic, input, named-characters

In Mathematica, there already exists a keyboard entry for 3-dot "Therefore", which provides great convenience for input as shown below.

[image]

However, I find it a little odd that for its counterpart, namely the 3-dot "Because", there seems no keyboard entry available as shown below.

[image]

So what puzzles me is, how I can self-define a keyboard entry for 3-dot "Because"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `InputAliases` to define an alias, like `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> {"be" -> "\[Because]"}]`.

This will create the alias <kbd>esc</kbd>`be`<kbd>esc</kbd> in the current notebook.

Note: in older versions of Mathematica, setting `InputAliases` in this way caused other aliases to get removed, requiring workarounds like the one outlined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68986/how-to-set-inputalias-for-all-future-notebooks-that-are-opened-in-current-sessio/68994#68994). It doesn't appear to function this way anymore, in 12.3 at least.

Comment: Thanks Carl, for your helpful suggestion, which did solve the problem to some degree. However, since I usually edit several notebooks in a particular sequence during a session, only setting the keyboard alias to the current opened notebook is a bit inconvenient as I need to set it for each notebook I open all over again during the same session. To satisfy my need completely, I modified the "EvaluationNotebook[]" in your coding to "$FrontEndSession" and it works perfectly ever since.

Comment: Great, glad to help!

Comment: To thank you for your revelatory insight, I have accepted your answer. Have a nice day!